# jpa-spring entitymanager.find timeout not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to implement pessimistic lock in my spring boot app with jpa and db as mysql. my objective is to have a repository first fetching a row from db and then setting lock on this. while this transaction is running nobody should be able to read the same row. Following is the code i have implemented:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepo {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 *
 * @param token
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public boolean lockUser(String token, int data) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 0);
        User usr = entityManager.find(User.class, token, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, props);
        System.out.println("BEFOREE LOCK = " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getId() + " user="+usr.getPlayerBalance());

        entityManager.lock(usr, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, props);
        System.out.println("AFTER LOCK = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (data>2) {
            System.out.println("IN IF BEFORE SLEEP Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Thread.sleep(90000);
            System.out.println("IN IF AFTER SLEEP Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("IN ELSE Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }  return false;
      }
 }
```

Now when i run this, when first request come with data > 3, this fetching row and then locks the row and thread sleeps for 90 sec. Now when second request comes with data = 1 then thread waits for lock (em.find-has pessimistic lock with timeout as 0 milliseconds). now ideally it should throw exception as i have set timeout to be 0. but second thread doesn't throw expcetion immediately, moreover thread reads row from db then waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` works for locking the row, that can be tested easily.

I adjusted the UserRepo a little to:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepo {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void lockUser(final Long id, final boolean wait) throws InterruptedException {
        entityManager.clear(); // be sure there is nothing in the cache, actually the threads don't share first level cache

        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 0);

        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " EXECUTES SELECT FOR UPDATE");
        entityManager.find(User.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, props);

        if (wait) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " started blocking!");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " finished blocking!");
        }

        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " FINISHED QUERY");
    }
}
```

And I created a (not beautiful but functional) test for that repo:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepoTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Test
    public void testSelectForUpdate() throws InterruptedException {

        final Runnable requestOne = () -> {
            try {
                userRepo.lockUser(1L, true); // this one should wait and block the others
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };

        final Runnable requestTwo = () -> {
            try {
                userRepo.lockUser(1L, false);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };

        final Runnable requestThree = () -> {
            try {
                userRepo.lockUser(1L, false);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };

        final Thread threadOne = new Thread(requestOne);
        threadOne.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000); // give the first one some time to start

        final Thread threadTwo = new Thread(requestTwo);
        threadTwo.start();
        final Thread threadThree = new Thread(requestThree);
        threadThree.start();

        Thread.sleep(20000); // wait before destroying context
    }

}
```

If we now assume there is an Entity of type User with the id 1 (Long) the output is:

```
Thread 16 EXECUTES SELECT FOR UPDATE
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_31_0_, user0_.player_balance as player_b2_31_0_ from "user" user0_ where user0_.id=? for update
Thread 16 started blocking!
Thread 17 EXECUTES SELECT FOR UPDATE
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_31_0_, user0_.player_balance as player_b2_31_0_ from "user" user0_ where user0_.id=? for update
Thread 18 EXECUTES SELECT FOR UPDATE
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_31_0_, user0_.player_balance as player_b2_31_0_ from "user" user0_ where user0_.id=? for update
Thread 16 finished blocking!
Thread 16 FINISHED QUERY
Thread 17 FINISHED QUERY
Thread 18 FINISHED QUERY
```

So all following executions of this query wait for the first one (because of the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE) after calling `entityManager.find(... LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE...);`, the `entityManager.lock(...)` call is not needed.

The missing exception could be caused by the fact that the query timeout is just a hint and is maybe not considered by your database. See [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions).

> QueryTimeoutException: the query takes longer than the specified timeout (see javax.persistence.query.timeout - this property is a hint and might not be followed)

Or also on the same page:

> javax.persistence.query.timeout query timeout in milliseconds (Integer or String), this is a hint used by Hibernate but requires support by your underlying database (TODO is that 100% true or do we use some other tricks).

So you should not rely on the timeout exception.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
I have used SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 0; COMMIT;
in mysql and now i am getting exception.
One more thing how can i unlock the row. I tried
entityManager.lock(usr, LockModeType.NONE);
but this doesn't remove lock. it will be great if you can please help.

Comment: I want to remove lock programatically before transaction ends.

Comment: The lock is released when the transaction ends. Maybe this helps: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/02/24/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/ The TransactiobTemplate could help to implement that: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html